# MySQL Trigger when Table Insert - External Program

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create a program that would detect when a new line is inserted into a MySQL Table.

I have looked through the MySQL Reference Documentation and can see there is a routine / trigger that can setup.
However this Trigger appears to only allow Insert / Append or Delete

Is there any way to call and external program? or a program / socket of some sort that can listen to the MySQL Database for when a Table has a new line inserted?

I am basically passing Data between two servers,

**Server A** - Is communicating with My Server **(Server Z)**

**Server B** - Is a local Server i need to pass Data down to (Not accessible Remotely only Local)

So i need to write a program that will accept a incoming connect for **Server B.** (This is not a problem)

But i want to know instantly when **Server A** has wrote to **Server Z**, to avoid any possible delay.

I can simply write a PHP / Python Program and have it run every 30 seconds, but 30 seconds is too long, i need to know within a couple of seconds max.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Opening Server B for remote connection is not possible for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [MySQL Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html). That is, any data change to Server Z will be repeated almost instantly on its replica, Server B.

It does require that Server B can connect over a network to Server Z, as if it is a MySQL client. It does not have to be connected 100% of the time, only while it is downloading changes to replicate. Server B does not need to accept remote connections. Replication works in a "pull" manner, so Server B is a client.

Another solution is to use some kind of CDC (Change Data Capture) tool such as [Debezium](https://debezium.io/). This work very similarly to MySQL Replication, in that it monitors a log of changes on the source instance, but it has more flexibility for what to do with those change events. Whereas MySQL Replication simply applies the same changes to another MySQL instance, a CDC tool can do other things for example post the events to a Kafka queue which can then be consumed any way you want.

I strongly urge you not to attempt to call external programs from a MySQL trigger. There are at least two problems with this:

First, triggers execute while the triggering action is still in progress. This means if you run an external program, the triggering action is blocked waiting for that program. This will appear to clients to be excessively degraded performance.

The second problem is that triggers execute while the calling transaction is not yet committed. If you run an external program to notify some other system of the change, but subsequently the transaction is rolled back, there's no way to "un-notify" the other system of that data change. The result is that you have notified the other system of a change that will never be visible in the source database.

Using the binary log is better, whether you use MySQL Replication or a CDC solution, because changes are not written to the binary log until the transaction is committed. Therefore events read from that log are by definition committed.

Comment: MySQL Replacement would be the best solution, but this is working from Different Data Sourced. Server Z, will contain Data for Multiple Clients, a separate program will extract this data to pass it over to the client. But this would of been my go to solution if it was possible. I was not aware the Triggers are called called before the Transaction is not completed, So thank you for pointing this out. I think i will utilise the Binary Logs to determine a Update / Change and then execute my program from this. Thank you

Comment: MySQL does support multi-source replication, but as you might expect it comes with some limitations. You should read about it and do a proof of concept before deciding on a solution. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-multi-source.html

Comment: I have a development environment setup and going through the the different possibilities. (Yet to commit to anything yet) I have looked and tried the Replication and it doesn't meet the requirements, There are limitation and possible problems that can and will occur. And on a Per client base (Using across 100 different Clients) Its a lot of setup / monitoring and possible complications. 
The Binary log at the moment seems the most reliable IF i can generate a fool proof method of constantly reading the log in realtime to trigger an event on a Insert statement then passing the data across.